# Define commands for frequently used text in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

Is there a way to define a command that can be used as a short cut for frequently used text or html commands in knitr when compiling to html?

I use knitr to compile an rmkardown file (`.Rmd`) and the output is a html file (i.e., I press *Knit HTML* in RStudio).

To be more specific, let me add an example: I want to separate the percent sign by a hair space from the number before, which I achieve by typing, e.g., `5&#8202;%`. It would be very convenient, if I could define a command, let's say `\perc`, that I can use instead, such that `5\perc` would be equivalent to  `5&#8202;%`.

Is this at all possible and if yes, how can it be done?

Comment: What format are you mixing with R? HTML, LaTeX, Markdown? What output format do you need?

Comment: I use rmakrdown (.Rmd file) with knitr to produce html output. As in the example, I use html input occasionally. When producing pdf output, I assume that I could use `\newcommand` as usual, but I don't know what to do when producing html output.

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward/built-in/cross-platform way to define macros in rmarkdown.  You could look into [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP).  It would be interesting to write a macro processor for markdown in R ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an R function and then call it inline. For example:

````
```{r}
perc <- function(){
  "&#8202;%" 
}
```
This is inline r code 5`r perc()`
````

I think you could also use it in chunks where the result would be 'asis'.

Comment: Thanks for your clever answer. Now that I see it, it seems so obious that I wonder how I could miss this... By the way, there is no need to define perc as a function, a simple string constant will do: `perc <- "&#8202;%"`.